# Is web automation with Openoffice BASIC even possible?

Tags: web-scraping, openoffice-basic

I'm trying to do some simple webscraping in OpenOffice (I usually work in Excel but I'm trying to port something over for a coworker that doesn't have Excel).  However, when I try to run something very similar to this, it keeps giving me this BASIC runtime error 1.

[image: error 1]

Here's the relevant code, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do to make this work.

```
Sub Macro1
    Dim explorer As Object
    Set explorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    explorer.Visible = True
    explorer.navigate("www.yahoo.com")
    
    Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE As Long = 4
    Do While explorer.Busy Or explorer.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    dim page as object
    set page = explorer.Document
    
    dim mailButton as object
    set mailButton = page.GetElementByID("ybar-navigation-item-mail") 'this is the line the error occurs on
    mailButton.Click
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that you can save script in `vbs` file (you have to delete types in variables declarations) and run it directly by double click without using office application? I recommend you to use this way.